# Load xml data into sql database using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know this is a really basic question but I am struggling on my first import of data from an xml file.  I have created the table "Regions" which has just two columns - ID and Name.  The xml file contains the same column names.

In order to bulk import the data, I am using the following SQL command:
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\regions.xml' 
INTO TABLE `Regions` (`ID`, `Name`)

but I am getting the error #1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Now having researched the internet, to allow this command requires a change in one of the command files but my service provider doesn't allow me access to it.  Is there an alternative way to write the SQL code and do exactly the same thing as the code above which is basically just import the data from an xml file?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you import CSV files?  If so, I would import the file into a spreadsheet program like Excel and then save the file as CSV.  If you can't use the INFILE structure at all, you can always create an insert SQL statement for each entry.  Again, the easiest way is to use Excel and use a formula to create the insert statement for each row.

Comment: Being completely rubbish at SQL, what would the SQL code be for importing the csv file?

Comment: Importing a CSV you would use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html.  You have to convert the XML file to a CSV file first, of course.

Comment: Having converted the file to csv, I used LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\regions.csv' 
INTO TABLE `Regions` (`ID`, `Name`) and got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since LOAD DATA INFILE isn't enabled for you, it appears you have only one more option and that's to create a set of INSERT statements for each row.  If you converted your XML file to CSV using Excel, that's an easy step.  Assuming you have a rows of data like this

```
 A   | B
-----|-------------------------
 1   | Region 1
 2   | Region 2
```

I would create a formula like this in column C

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO Regions(ID,Name) VALUES(",A1,",'",B1,"');")
```

This will result in `INSERT INTO Regions(ID,Name) VALUES(1,'Region 1');` for your first row. File this down to the last row of your spreadsheet. Select all the insert statements and copy them into a Query text box inside PHPMyAdmin and you should be able to insert your values.

I've used this method many times when I needed to import data into a database.